# Access Host Machine IIS from Hyper-V VM

Tags: iis, hyper-v

I'm pretty new to Hyper-V so go easy on me if this is an obvious question.  I would like to access my host machine's IIS through a Hyper-V VM so that I can view webpages I'm creating in Visual Studio within my VM. I have enabled the network switch to share internet connection however I'm unsure as to how I can allow IIS through to my VM.  Is this simply a firewall/port issue or is there a more advanced solution needed?

Comment: Nothing here is too specific to Hyper-V, as it's comparable to a case of networking between two isolated machines. You just need to ensure the host and VM can communicate with each other. But when you say you want to view the host's "webpages", do you mean the actual site or the configuration in IIS manager?

Comment: I have a website running on my local IIS deployed through visual studio. I would like to access that localhost site inside of my VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a switch attached to the VM, I don't see anything that is required to be done on the VM, but I would ping the host from VM and make sure that works.

If you are running the website just out of Visual Studio, which would inturn be running IIS Express and not the IIS on the host, you should follow the instructions here to configure IIS express and host to accept requests from non local addresses: http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer.